# Inno Setup: Generated folder name works in Windows XP but not Windows 7

Tags: windows, inno-setup

In the [Files] section, I use a Pascal scripting which calls my own DLL to generate a folder name where I want my program documentation to be installed. My DLL and my Pascal script appear to be working properly, but when I run my installer on Windows 7, Inno Setup uses the directory name as the file name instead of appending the file name to the directory name, and I end up getting all 3 documentation files copied into a file that has the name that I wanted the directory to have. Oddly, the code does work properly when I run it on Windows XP.

Here is some of the relevant code:

The [Files] section:

```
[Files]
Source: "doc 1.pdf"; DestDir: "{code:DocumentFolder}";
Source: "doc 2.pdf"; DestDir: "{code:DocumentFolder}";
Source: "doc 3.pdf"; DestDir: "{code:DocumentFolder}";
```

The Pascal script:

```
// Get the path to the documentation folder
// DocPath() returns a path name without a trailing backslash
// unless it returns a null string.
function DocumentFolder(Param: String) : String;
var
  s : String;
  k : integer;
begin
  SetLength(s, 255);
  k := DocPath(s); // Path to "MyCompany\MyProg" folder or something like it
  if 0 = k then s := ExpandConstant('{app}'); // Just use the program folder if there is no public folder
  Result := s; 
end;
```

The reason I am scripting at all is that I'd like to have the documentation go into a folder within the system's public folder if there is one, but alternately into the program folder on a system with no public folder.

If I have missed some totally easy way to do that, kindly let me know.

Anyway, when I run this on a Windows 7 system, here is what I get, according to Inno Setup's debug log:

```
[10:47:42.406]   Dest filename: C:\Users\Public\MyCompany\MyProgDocs
[10:47:42.409]   Time stamp of our file: 2002-07-10 10:33:02.000
[10:47:42.412]   Installing the file.
[10:47:42.453]   Successfully installed the file.
[10:47:42.458]   -- File entry --
[10:47:44.595]   Dest filename: C:\Users\Public\MyCompany\MyProgDocs
[10:47:44.598]   Time stamp of our file: 2014-09-13 21:14:36.000
[10:47:44.600]   Dest file exists.
[10:47:44.601]   Time stamp of existing file: 2002-07-10 10:33:02.000
[10:47:44.603]   Version of our file: (none)
[10:47:44.609]   Version of existing file: (none)
[10:47:44.611]   Installing the file.
[10:47:44.637]   Successfully installed the file.
[10:47:44.640]   -- File entry --
[10:47:45.603]   Dest filename: C:\Users\Public\MyCompany\MyProgDocs
[10:47:45.606]   Time stamp of our file: 2014-09-16 14:51:26.000
[10:47:45.608]   Dest file exists.
[10:47:45.610]   Time stamp of existing file: 2014-09-13 21:14:36.000
[10:47:45.612]   Version of our file: (none)
[10:47:45.615]   Version of existing file: (none)
[10:47:45.617]   Installing the file.
[10:47:45.710]   Successfully installed the file.
```

As you can see, each of my 3 PDF files have been copied into a file named `C:\Users\Public\MyCompany\MyProgDocs` instead of `C:\Users\Public\MyCompany\MyProgDocs\doc 1.pdf` etc. as I intended. The destination file is created by the first line in the [Files] section, and is then overwritten by the second, and overwritten again by the third.

By stepping thru with the debugger, I see that my Pascal script and the DLL that supports it are working properly.

The call `DocPath(s)` returns the number of characters in the string, and sets its parameter `s` to the string value I want. On XP, it returns a zero and sets `s` to the null string. On Windows 7, `DocPath(s)` returns 36 and sets `s` to `C:\Users\Public\MyCompany\MyProgDocs`.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
Here is some of the relevant code from my DLL:

```
#define FOLDERNAME _T("MyCompany")
static CString GetPublicPath()
{
    TCHAR pubpath[_MAX_PATH] = {_T("")};
    int nameSize = ::GetEnvironmentVariable(_T("public"), pubpath, countof(pubpath));
    if (0 < nameSize)
    {
        TCHAR* wdbuf = _tgetcwd(NULL, 0);
        _tchdir(pubpath);
        _tmkdir(FOLDERNAME);
        _tchdir(FOLDERNAME);
        _tcscat(pubpath, _T("\\"));
        _tcscat(pubpath, FOLDERNAME);
        _tchdir(wdbuf);
        free(wdbuf);
    }

    return CString(pubpath);
}
int STDCALL DocPath(wchar_t** x)
{
    CString docpath = GetPublicPath();
    docpath = StripBackslash(docpath);
    if (0 < docpath.GetLength())
    {
        docpath += _T("\\MyProgDocs");
    }
    _tcscpy(*x, docpath.GetBuffer());
    ::MessageBox(0, *x, _T("DLL DocPath()"), MB_OK);
    return _tcslen(*x);
}
```

I don't have the call to `MessageBox()` in the production version but it has been useful for debugging. The macro `countof` is like `sizeof` but returns an array count rather than a byte size so it works properly for wide characters.

Comment: What does the DocPath function do?

Comment: `DocPath()` examines the environment variable `Public` (if it exists) to get the path to the public folder.

Comment: As a side effect, `GetPublicPath()` which is called by `DocPath()` also creates the target directory in Windows 7, but not XP. I now wonder if that is the problem and will investigate further.

Comment: I modified `GetPublicPath()` so that it does not create the target directory; it just gets the path. This did not make any difference; Inno Setup still does not append the document name when it copies my PDF files.

Comment: You could expand the `{userdocs}` constant and the result would be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If k > 0 you must set the lenght of s to k.
But it is much easier to get the environment variable from inno (and unnecessary to write a dll) - for example:

```
function DocumentFolder(dummy: String): String;
var
  s: String;
begin
  s := GetEnv('public');
  if Length(s) > 0 then
     s := s + '\MyCompany\MyProgDocs'
  else
    s := ExpandConstant('{app}');
  Result := s;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! That will do it nicely!